# Is there a way to get a blank xcworkspace to work with gym through cli?

Tags: fastlane

If I want to have a clean cordova build, I'm not supposed to include the ios platform, instead it gets generated on the build server together with everything else.

I can generate xcworkspace via xcode on CI. But is there some way of configuring xcode over cli like here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/XcodeProject/#setting-up-your-xcode-project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I ended up creating a [Fastlane plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/bamlab/fastlane-plugin-cordova) to solve this.

See how to use it in [this blog post](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/deploy-a-new-cordova-app-to-testflight-in-5-minutes-with-fastlane) or below:

### Use the Cordova Fastlane plugin

Add the [Cordova Fastlane Plugin](https://github.com/Almouro/fastlane-plugin-cordova) to your project:

```
fastlane add_plugin cordova
```

When asked `Should fastlane modify the Gemfile at path 'Gemfile' for you? (y/n)`, reply with `y`.

Then you can integrate the plugin into your Fastlane setup, for example:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Deploy ios app on the appstore"

  lane :create do
    produce(app_name: "myapp")
  end

  lane :deploy do
    match(
      type: "appstore",
      git_url: "https://bitbucket.org/Almouro/certificates" # REPLACE WITH YOUR PRIVATE REPO FOR MATCH
    )
    cordova(platform: 'ios') # Using the Cordova Fastlane Plugin
    appstore(ipa: ENV['CORDOVA_IOS_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
  end
end

platform :android do
  desc "Deploy android app on play store"

  lane :deploy do
    cordova(
      platform: 'android',
      keystore_path: './prod.keystore', # REPLACE THESE LINES WITH YOUR KEYSTORE INFORMATION
      keystore_alias: 'prod',
      keystore_password: 'password'
    ) # Cordova Fastlane Plugin
    supply(apk: ENV['CORDOVA_ANDROID_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
  end
end
```

with an `Appfile` such as

```
app_identifier "com.awesome.app"
apple_id "apple@id.com"
team_id "28323HT"
```

**Piece of cake now!**

For iOS, run `fastlane ios create` once to create your app on the developer member center and iTunes Connect.

Now, you only have to run `fastlane ios deploy` and `fastlane android deploy` to deploy to the stores!

### Where to go from here

- You can see all the plugin options by running `fastlane actions cordova` at the root of your Cordova app
- If you have any issue or idea for improvement on the plugin, please make them know [here](https://github.com/bamlab/fastlane-plugin-cordova/issues)